# Dimension of intersection of affine subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-programming, affine-geometry, convex-hulls

As an assignment we are to calculate the dimension of the intersection of two affine subspaces $A$,$B$ in $\mathbb{R}^6$ each defined by a system of linear equations of at most 6 variables and a constant.

How does one calculate that?

I tried to stack together the equations and simplify, then parametrize the solution as a $\vec v$ + {set of parametrized vectors}. 
Then the dimensionality of their intersection should be the size of the set. But when I carry out the calculations I get a contradiction.

Is my procedure valid?
How else could I arrive at the solution? What are other methods of finding the intersection?

*Edit:
Does contradiction indicate that the intersection is empty?

*Edit2: I add code I used to check if I made any numerical errors.
After running the code, result is EmptySet()

The first 3 rows of $M$ is the augumented form of $A$.

The bottom 3 rows of $M$ is the augumented form of $B$

```
import sympy

M = Matrix([
[3, 4,  6,  0,  0,  0, 3],
[4, 0,  0,  1,  1,  0, 2],
[0, 1, -4,  0,  0,  0, 8],
[0, 1,  1, -1, -1,  2, 0],
[0, 0, -1,  1,  1, -2, 0],
[0, 1, -7,  0,  0,  0, 0]])

x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6 = sympy.symbols('x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6')
result = sympy.linsolve(M,(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6))
```

Comment: If $A$ is a subspace, then what does the "augmented form of $A$" refer to?

Comment: Clarification for others: based on [how the linsolve method](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve) works, it seems that "$P$ is the augmented form of $A$" means that $A$ is the solution set to the equation $Qx = b$, where $P = [Q \mid b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: the fact that you got the output `EmptySet()` indicates that the intersection of the two affine spaces is empty.

Using W|A [confirms this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row%20reduce%20%20%7B%20%7B3%2C%204%2C%20%206%2C%20%200%2C%20%200%2C%20%200%2C%203%7D%2C%20%7B4%2C%200%2C%20%200%2C%20%201%2C%20%201%2C%20%200%2C%202%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%201%2C%20-4%2C%20%200%2C%20%200%2C%20%200%2C%208%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%201%2C%20%201%2C%20-1%2C%20-1%2C%20%202%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%200%2C%20-1%2C%20%201%2C%20%201%2C%20-2%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%201%2C%20-7%2C%20%200%2C%20%200%2C%20%200%2C%200%7D%7D).